# Android Searchable dictionary

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm relatively new to Android and I'm working on my first application,A dictionary.Till now, I'm able to display the list of words and provide for a mechanism to add words in a bookmarks list but I'm not able to figure out how to add the search functionality using fts3 in Sqlite.What I require is to provide suggestions when the user searches for a particular word in the application. Can someone tell me how to proceed??

Answer (score 0):

[AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) will help you.

Comment: I figured another way.Instead of  using AutoCompleteTextView I used search filter using setFilterQueryProvider().